# Using qsort()/qsort_r() on btrlib didn't work

Tags: c, gcc

im trying to use the C standard library `qsort()` function to sort an
array of [bstring](https://github.com/websnarf/bstrlib) and didn't work,
according to bstrlib:

```c
    typedef struct tagbstring * bstring;
    typedef const struct tagbstring * const_bstring;
```

my comparator callback is:

````c
int cmp_bstring(const void *a, const void *b, void *unused) {
  (void)unused;
    return bstrcmp((const_bstring)a, (const bstring)b);
}
```c

then i setup some simple code to test, call `qsort\_r()` on this data and the array
remains unsorted:

```c
  bstring strings[] = {
    bfromcstr("Three"),
    bfromcstr("One"),
    bfromcstr("Two"),
  };

  printf("-- Unordered Array --\n");
  print_array(strings, SizeArray(strings));

  qsort_r(strings, SizeArray(strings), sizeof(bstring), cmp_bstring, NULL);

  printf("\n-- Ordered Array --\n");
  print_array(strings, SizeArray(strings));
}
````

the full code is:

```c
 #ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
 #define _GNU_SOURCE
 #endif

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include "bstrlib.h"

 #define SizeArray(arr) (sizeof((arr)) / sizeof((arr)[0]))

int cmp_bstring(const void *a, const void *b, void *unused) {
  (void)unused;
    return bstrcmp((const_bstring)a, (const bstring)b);
}

void print_array(bstring array[], unsigned array_len) {
    for (unsigned i=0; i < array_len; i++)
        printf("[%d] = %s\n", i, array[i]->data);
}

int main(void) {
  bstring strings[] = {
    bfromcstr("Three"),
    bfromcstr("One"),
    bfromcstr("Two"),
  };

  printf("-- Unordered Array --\n");
  print_array(strings, SizeArray(strings));

  qsort_r(strings, SizeArray(strings), sizeof(bstring), cmp_bstring, NULL);

  printf("\n-- Ordered Array --\n");
  print_array(strings, SizeArray(strings));
}
```

The expected output is:

```
-- Unordered Array --
[0] = Three
[1] = One
[2] = Two

-- Ordered Array --
[0] = One
[2] = Three
[3] = Two
```

but i get:

```
-- Unordered Array --
[0] = Three
[1] = One
[2] = Two

-- Ordered Array --
[0] = Three
[1] = One
[2] = Two
```

by the way, why `SizeArray` macro didn't work if i use it into `print_array()`
function (returns 1), and from `main()` returns correct array size?

Built with GCC on Linux

Comment: BTW question, because you cannot use that size calculation method on a pure pointer. Sizeof(poiter) is always 4 or 8 , not the size of the array

Comment: If you don't have a use for a third argument to your comparison function then why are you working with `qsort_r()`?  Its *only* difference from ordinary `qsort()` is that it receives that extra argument (that you don't care about) and passes it on in each call of the comparison function (which doesn't use it).

Comment: On a tangent: Using `typedef` on pointers is often thought to be a bad practice. It makes it much harder to reason about the code when there are issues. Many think using `typedef` on structs at all is counter-productive, too, but that's more subjective.

Comment: Oh, now i see, thanks pm100.

Comment: Im use qsort_r() only but get the habit to use reentrant/threadsafe functions, but  qsort() have the same behavior in my case.

Comment: `qsort()` is not inherently any less reentrant than `qsort_r()` is.  The latter caters to special cases where the comparison function needs to refer to additional, variable data beyond the addresses and values of the two objects to compare.  That scenario is unusual.

Comment: Is qsort() reentrant too? what about threadsafe?, and why man 3 qsort_r says *"The  qsort_r()  function is identical to qsort() except that the comparison function compar takes a third argument.
       A pointer is passed to the comparison function via arg.  In this way, the comparison function does not need to  use
       global variables to pass through arbitrary arguments, and is therefore reentrant and safe to use in threads."*, That looks as qsort_r() is for reentrant/threadsafe uses, No?

Comment: @anewb33, focus on the first part of that: "The `qsort_r()` function is identical to `qsort()` except that the comparison function `compar` takes a third argument".  This addresses the possibility that *the comparison function* is not thread safe on account of accessing variable external data (via global variables).  The comparison function is of course provided by the caller.  `qsort()` is not inherently any less thread-safe than `qsort_r()`.  The latter has its uses, but for typical comparison behavior, such as yours appears to be, `qsort()` is just fine in multithreaded programs.

Comment: Note also that if `bstrcmp()` were not thread safe then using `qsort_r()` instead of `qsort()` would not make your usage thread safe.  The docs you quoted rather overstate the case.  You need to understand the mechanism (an extra argument, which is passed through to the comparison function, and nothing more) and why that ever helps to understand which cases benefit from `qsort_r()`.

Comment: Ok, now understand your point, [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger), was a bad interpretation from me, thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have become confused about levels of indirection.  Pretend that you don't know the definition of `bstring`, and in particular, you don't know that it is a pointer type.  Would you then think it made sense to convert pointers into `bstring`s?

`qsort()`'s comparison function receives *pointers to* the values being compared, not the values themselves.  Therefore, you appear to be looking for this variation:

```
int cmp_bstring(const void *a, const void *b, void *unused) {
  (void)unused;
    return bstrcmp(*(const_bstring *)a, *(const bstring *)b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks [Jonh Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger), that was the problem, as [hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717300/hyde) comment, the typedef tends to confuse when the types are unfamiliar.